# How to send Email in Django using office365

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, outlook, rest

I am working in a project where I need to send the email to the user who is filling the Email in the form. I am able to send email by using my `Gmail Account` details but while using `outlook.365`. [This is the image with error that I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf84o.png)

**My requirement is :**

1. Once users come in the registration form and fill the details as Name, Email, Mobile
2. Whatever Email is put there in the form, send the email with link to create new password.

**Here is my code:**

`settings.py:`

```
 # Using outlook365:

 EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
 EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'support@academic.com'
 EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.outlook.office365.com'  # (also tried : smtp.office365.com  and  
 outlook.office365.com)

 EMAIL_PORT = 587
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'My_Password'


 # Using my gmail account:

 EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
 EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@gmail.com'
 EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
 EMAIL_PORT = 587
 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'My_Password'
```

`views.py:`

```
 subject = "Academic - Create New Password"
 message = "Hi %s! Please create your new Password here : http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-password"  % firstname

 send_mail(
        subject,  # Subject of the email
        message,  # Body or Message of the email
        'support@academic.com',  # from@gmail.com   (admin@gmail.com for gmail account)
        [email],  # to@gmail.com  # email that is filled in the form
    )
```

**Please guide me that what extra setting or configuration I need to send email using Outlook365.**

Answer (score 0):

Please put this in **settings.py** file.

```
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: I am getting same error. Is that same what you are saying :


     ```EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'```

     ```EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'support@academic.com'```

     ```SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER```

     ```EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.outlook.office365.com'```

     ```EMAIL_PORT = 587```

     ```EMAIL_USE_TLS = True```

     ```EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'My_Password'```

Answer (score 0):

Your settings look correct. Use `EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.office365.com"`. Verify that you are using the correct credentials. Check that your outlook account is set up properly to send emails from `support@academic.com`.